# how to permission to Designer only FrontEnd Folder in GitLAB

Tags: git, gitlab

i have Project in GitLAB and i need my designer Only access to:

Folder: projectName/frontend/css , js , font , images

File: projectName/frontend/index.html

designer dont access to Other files and folders.

Comment: You probably have to split your project in 2 separate projects, 1 for designers and 1 for developers

Comment: this is not good , Control of the project difficult.

Comment: You can't do this sort of thing in GitLab. Use git submodules with 2 different projects as @Jawad suggested to do this.